# How do you use the vertex property on gstreamer's glshader element?

Tags: glsl, shader, gstreamer

gstreamer has an element called `glshader` with properties like `fragment` and `vertex`.  The documentation includes an example of trivial fragment shader, but as of 1.16 does not include an example of a vertex shader.

What kind of skeleton should be used to start writing my own vertex shader for use with the glshader element?

Answer (score 2):

While the documentation is currently sparse, you can find an example in the [gst-plugins-base package in gst-libs/gst/gl/gstglshaderstrings.c](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/blob/bdb3bccc557003f5698df8bfa76035817137c24b/gst-libs/gst/gl/gstglshaderstrings.c#L44).

It looks like

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
void main()
{
   gl_Position = a_position;
   v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
```

A good starting point for testing your shaders is

```
gst-launch-1.0 gltestsrc ! glshader fragment="\"`frag_shader`\"" vertex="\"`vert_shader`\"" ! glimagesink
```

If you add something like `v_texcoord.y*=0.8;` you can demonstrate that the geometry glshader is feeding into the shader is a rectangle with `v=0` on the top, which is backwards from how Unity interprets texture coordinates (Unity uses v=0 for the bottom except when you get to close to the metal on a system with different conventions).  An experiment like `v_texcoord.y *= 2.0;` demonstrates that the default wrap mode seems to be `CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.